# Nonabelian $p$-groups all of whose proper subgroups are abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

> **Theorem.**
>   Let $G$ be a finite, non-abelian $p$-group all of whose proper subgroups are abelian. Then $|G'|=p$.

Take a counterexample of minimal order. Assume that exist a $H$  such that $1<H<G'$.
 Then (by $G'\leq \Phi (G) \leq Z(G)$) $H\vartriangleleft G$. From this we deduce we can assume $|G'|\leq p^2$.

Then? How am I supposed to continue?

**Edit**
*Additional infos*
$G'$ is elementary abelian since $G$ is Frattini-in-center.

Comment: We see this nice deduction when $|G|=p^3$ and the group is non-abelian and finite.

Comment: May I know why should $\Phi(G)<Z(G)$?

Comment: Since $G$ isn't abelian we can find two distinct maximal subgroups (each of one is abelian), say $U1, U2$.
Then $<U1,U2>=G$. The intersection of $U1$ and $U2$ is central. Am I wrong?

Comment: $G$ is a finite $p$-group, so it is obviously nilpotent (of class 2, in this case).
The center and the commutator subgroup of $Q_8$ are the same, $\{1,-1\}$, so it's true for it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "equals" above :D

Comment: I only want to make sure: did you mean to write, one line before the last one,$$"\text{Then}\,\,\left(G'\leq\Phi(G)\leq Z(G)\right)\,\,H\triangleleft G"\,\,?$$ And if you did, why $\,H\triangleleft G\,$?

Comment: Yes. Something wrong?
$H<G'\leq Z(G)$, then $H\vartriangleleft G$ (subgroups of the center are trivially normal)

Comment: It just looked funny: two lines before the end the line *ends* with a left parentheses "(", so I all the time thought you meant $\,\Phi(G)\leq Z(G)H\,$...the right, closing, parentheses looked like a typo. Perhaps it'd be a good idea to jump a line there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking...
$G$ is a finite, nilpotent (so also soluble) group; so there exist a $G_1\vartriangleleft G$ such that $|G:G_1|=p$. $G$ is minimal non abelian, hence $G=<x, y>$. We can suppose $y\notin G_1$, but then there exist a $g\in G_1$ such that $y^n=xg$; so $G=<y,g>$. Then, as above, $G'=[G_1,y]$ and every $x\in G'$ is a product of element of the form $[y^{n_1}g^{m_1}...y^{n_t}g^{m_t}, y^c]$. Hence every $x\in G'$ has the form: $[g^m, y^s]=[g, y]^{k}$.
$G'$ is cyclic and elementary abelian, since $G$ is Frattini-in-center, so $|G'|=p$.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at page $6$ of [Miller and Moreno](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1903-004-04/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9.pdf).

Comment: "As  this  subgroup  and $s$ must  generate  $G$,  it  follows  that  the  commutator  subgroup  of  $G$  is
of  order  $p$".  
"this subgroup" referes to $G_1$?  
In such a case: $[G, G]\leq [G_1 , s]$ (since $G$ is nilpotent). But then? How can we use the p-group-fact?